# Can't delete single ekevent of recurrent event in calendar iOS

Tags: ios, calendar, exchange-server, eventkit, ekevent

I've developed an app that uses calendar using the eventkit.

The user can push a button and delete a specific event. Everything works just fine, except when it comes to recurrent events.

If the user itself created  the recurrent events, it works as expected, the single event is deleted and the rest remains in calendar. But if the recurrent events is created by other and accepted by user and then try to delete one specific of those events, they all disappear from calendar. Why?

In this case iPad only uses  one Exchange calendar, can the problem be Exchange specific?

```
/* Get the Exchange Calendar */  
EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];  
NSError* error = nil;  
NSMutableArray* calendars = [[store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent] mutableCopy];  
NSMutableArray* cals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
for (EKCalendar *cal in calendars) {  
     if (cal.type == EKCalendarTypeExchange) {  
          [cals addObject:cal];  
          break;  
     }  
}  
/* get the correct event, get Events with startDate & endDate and differ with eventId */  
// (tappedEvent = event to remove)  
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[tappedEvent valueForKey:@"from"] endDate:[tappedEvent valueForKey:@"to"] calendars:cals];  
NSArray *theEvents=[store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];  
NSString *recurrenceEventIdentifier = [tappedEvent valueForKey:@"appID"];  
for(EKEvent * theEvent in theEvents){  
     if([theEvent.eventIdentifier isEqualToString: recurrenceEventIdentifier] && ![store removeEvent:theEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]){  
          NSLog(@"Error in removing event: %@",error);  
     }  
}  
[store commit:&error];  
if(error){  
     ...  
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what the values for `@"from"` and `@"to"` are. Are you certain you're not looping over events from multiple days (thus deleting all recurrence events from the given period)?

Comment: from and to are start & enddate for the event, since all events in a recurrent event in store have the same eventIdentifier i need to separate the one to delete from the others. This is working since when user created the recurrent events everything works as it should. It's only recurrent events that's been accepted by the user and created by other that's not working. for example: my colleague creates an recurrent event and invites me to it, I accept and all events will be added to my calendar. then in my app i use the function to delete one of those events.

Comment: My guess is there's an issue with the start/end date. You could loop through a larger period (adding 1 day margin on each side) and see if that's the case based on what recurrent events you find. Also check if the timezone for your events is maybe different than the timezone of your colleague's events.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try to clarify the issue: Everything works just fine, except when an account in exchange creates a recurrent event and invites my account to the event, now at this point if I from my account use my app to delete a single event from this recurrent chain of events, They all disappear. But if I, using my own account, Create a chain of events (recurrent) and do the same procedure mentioned above, only one (the one matching @"from" and @"to") is deleted from calendar. So I don't think it is a start/end issue.

Comment: I see your point. Since you want to delete just 1 event, you could break your for loop once a matching event is found. So in case `theEvents` contains all the repeats for some reason, you'd just be deleting the first one.

Comment: yes that's true, I could indeed put in a "break" for loop but this won't change anything about the issue thou since there will be only one event with the correct id in the events array. this is driving me nuts.

Comment: on the other hand, who knows, in the case where another user created the recurrent event the store might return all events connected to the predicate. I will try. I Think i debugged it once and inspected the Events array and confirmed that only one single event was in there but i can be wrong..

Comment: Did you find any solutions? We come across the same problem. Deleting one recursive exchange event, deletes all events. Interesting is that there is no cancel option for this events in the iOS system calendar, but you can decline it, which works as it is expected. Problem is that there is no possibility to decline events in iOS API.